# Align Console Text

Tags: c++, windows, console, windows-10, console-application

I've recently switched from Visual Studio 2010 to 2017 and I've noticed that it aligns text in a console application differently.

Previously, the 2010 version would leave a few spaces from the console to text and with the 2017 version, the text aligned on the left side hugs the console application.

My question is, is there anyway I could permutably align the text to have a couple spaces between the console and text instead of hugging it?

Comment: It isn't clear to me how Visual Studio could be responsible for aligning console text in the first place.  I think we'll need a [mcve].  Or at least a screenshot to show what you mean.  (Are you certain this is a Visual Studio change and not because you've moved from Windows 7 to Windows 10?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston It would look like the link down below. I want to have a few spaces between the console and Hello World. https://www.google.com/search?biw=1420&bih=712&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=visual+studio+console+application&oq=visual+studio+console+application&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i24k1l3.5498.7714.0.7836.9.9.0.0.0.0.172.682.1j5.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.3.309.XEl8M56flsM#imgrc=vKuysza8HxgmvM:

Comment: @eryksun Whoops I am sorry. Here it is. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/V9FPncJK17A/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: @eryksun Is there any way I can configure those options to change it?

Comment: Without a "before" picture I'm not entirely sure what you're talking about; do you just mean that there used to be a very thin strip of black between the text and the window border?  Have you checked that the display scaling is set to 100% and not, e.g., 125%?

Comment: @eryksun, oh I see, you think the OPs screenshot is the "before" picture, showing what he wants to happen?  I interpreted it as the "after" picture, showing the behaviour he *didn't* want.  OP, could you please clarify?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I think I was mistaken. Anyway, I can't remember whether the Windows 7 console adds a bit of padding in the client area. I don't see a difference when I enable the "legacy console" option in Windows 10. I also don't know what can be done in code to modify this. Maybe one could mange it dynamically by making the screen buffer a bit smaller than the window. I think this would require code to check for screen-resize input events and constant updates to correct the layout.

Comment: @eryksun, the console in the OPs screenshot looks more like Windows 7 (or perhaps Windows 8.1?) than it does like Windows 10.  Apart from the border being a different width, the relationship between the border and the text looks just the same to me on 7 and 10.  So I think your interpretation of what the OP meant is correct and mine was wrong. :-)  At any rate, I think this all belongs in the "you'll just have to get used to it" bucket.